# Why in this example in "applyAll" function , parameter after argument setted 1, not 0 ?

Tags: javascript, call, apply

```
     function sum() {
          return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
          });
        }

        function mul() {
          return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
            return a * b;
          });
        }
```

why there is a second parameter is 1? If we want shift all array or argumentsm, it`s like we need to to set start parameter 1 , not 0. Cause if we used 1 , we will lost argument with key 0.

```
function applyAll(func) { 
                      return func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
                  }

            console.log( applyAll(sum, 1, 2, 3) ); // 6
            console.log( applyAll(mul, 2, 3, 4) ); // 24
            console.log( applyAll(Math.max, 2, -2, 3) ); // 3
            console.log( applyAll(Math.min, 2, -2, 3) ); // -2
```

This is how used [].slice.call(context, arg).

```
    var obj= [1,2,3];
    console.log([].slice.call(obj,0));


    (function() {
    return [].slice.call(arguments,0)
    }(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is the **context** (as in, what `this` will be inside the function). Second argument and over are the arguments sent into the function.

Answer (score 0):

For the function `applyAll`, the first argument is always `func`.

So in your code example `applyAll(sum, 1, 2, 3)`, the arguments is `[sum, 1, 2, 3]`. What you are supposed to do is passing `1, 2, 3` as arguments to `sum`. That is why you need to get a sub array from **index = 1** from the original arguments which is `[sum, 1, 2, 3]`.

---

**Answer to your comments:**

I thought you should have the clue:

```
[sum, 1, 2, 3].slice(1) = [1, 2, 3]
```

see? You should pass **1** to `slice`. That is the answer. Don't confuse the **context** with the arguments pseudo-array itself.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I didn't ask correctly, but I know that first argument is context and second is argument. I want to ask why value of this argument is 1 , not 0? Cause in other more simple examples, when we work with [].slice, if we want to shift all array or pseudo-array arguments we can to set "start" argument zero, but not 1. Because if we set argument 1, we will lost argument with key 0.